# sql - How to only apply condition in WHERE if condition is met

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble implementing this, where I want to have the condition in WHERE removed/added if a condition is met.

sample:

```
select x.color, x.shape
from table x
x.finish = 'shine'
```

What I want this to do is that if `x.color` is not, for example, 'Red', then `x.finish = 'shine'` in `WHERE` should not apply.

TIA!

Comment: `x.color <> 'Red' OR x.finish = 'shine'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OR` to match the conditions when `color` is not equal to 'Red' (which is when it is either not equal to `'Red'` or when it is `NULL`):

```sql
SELECT color,
       shape
FROM   table_name
WHERE  color != 'Red'
OR     color IS NULL
OR     finish = 'shine'
```